# How response unauthorized user in Spring Security own way

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need return to client http code 401 with some JSON from spring security filter, when user entered wrong credentials.

Security conf:

```
<http pattern="/log/**" use-expressions="true" name="restSecurityFilterChain" create-session="stateless">
    <http-basic/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="userService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

authentification provider:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    User user = repository.getByNameAndPass(name, password);
    if (user == null) {
        name = "NotAuthorised";
        password = "";
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
    return auth;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

Here I log wrong user, as "NotAuthorised" to my Controller.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>  getAll(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size) {

    Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    String loggedUser = userService.getLoggedUser();
    if ("NotAuthorised".equals(loggedUser)) {
        LOG.info("authtoriation error");
        resultMap.put("message","Access denied");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resultMap, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    LOG.info("getAll for logmessages ");
    resultMap.put("logs", logMessageService.getLogMessagesDT(logMessageService.getPage(page == null ? 0 :
            page.intValue(), size == null ? 0 : size.intValue())) );

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resultMap, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And after entering wrong credentials Spring ask credentials twice, and return status 0 & "" JSON here:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(resultMap, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
```

If I return not 401 status - all ok.

Comment: You probably can use an AuthenticationFailureHandler for that.